# django cant connect to tablespace

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to make a website with the help of which it will be possible to change, watch, add entries to an already made database. I chose django for this. Previously i successfully connected to this tablespace

**Error application:**

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  tablespace "AAA" does not exist
```

**Frist models.py**

```
class svod_lic(models.Model):
    bot=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return  {self.bot}
    class Meta:
        db_table='prim'
        db_tablespace="AAA"
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'AAA': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'AAA',
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
        'HOST': '192.168.0.30',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

**Second models.py with error**

```
class ksg_npp(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(),
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1000),
    c_prof=models.IntegerField(),
    smj_prof=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField()
    )
    KSG=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = "AAA"
        db_table = 'ksg_npp'
```

Honestly i dnot even know why it`s happening pls help i am desperate. I even tried to do it in another app and still this error shows up

**Upd:** Ok somehow now the table shows up but still, when i trying to migrate it still shows that tablespace doesn't exist. Maybe it`s because i didn't create table with django model, but just read it in already existing database.

Comment: Why are you specifying a tablespace in the first place?  And does it exist?

Comment: @jjanes, because i want to show table info, not to create new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in that i called tablesapce and put ,.

**Second models.py with error**

```
class ksg_npp(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField(),
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1000),
    c_prof=models.IntegerField(),
    smj_prof=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField()
    )
    KSG=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = "AAA"
        db_table = 'ksg_npp'
```

**Correct models.pyr**

```
class ksg_npp(models.Model):
    id=models.IntegerField()
    name=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    c_prof=models.IntegerField()
    smj_prof=ArrayField(
        models.IntegerField()
    )
    KSG=models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ksg_npp'
```